# What do you say to bus driver in this situation?

Tags: spoken-english

Let's say you're on the bus and you ring the bell one stop earlier and bus driver's going to stop the bus. You want to say to him or her that you rang it by accident. What is the most natural way to say it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would simply say to the bus driver :

> I rang the bell by accident. My mistake.

Depending on the bus driver (such as if they are angry), this may receive a shrug or sometimes an annoyed response. However, most bus drivers here in the California will simply say something then continue on as if nothing has happened.

Comment: Do you say "on accident" in California?  To this New Yorker, it sounds a little strange; we would usually say *by* accident.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. My apologies and my answer now reflects that suggestion.

Comment: [EL&U on on accident](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saying 'Oops! Sorry! While flapping hand back and forth, like, waving, and making pained expression on face.

As he/she is unlikely to hear you well over the sound of the engine, and will most likely not need to much prompting to understand your meaning. Sometimes, body language is easier to use than words!